# PowerShell Exchange 2003 quest: Is there a way to query if ActiveSync is enabled?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, activesync, exchange-server-2003

Using Quest PowerShell on a Windows 2003 Server running Exchange 2003, is there a way to query if a user's ActiveSync or OMA is enabled or disabled?

---

EDIT: This is arguably a duplicate of [your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338428/exchange-powershell-is-there-a-way-to-query-who-are-activesyncbb-users) from Dec. 3, 2008.

EDIT: That question referred to Exchange 2007.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338428 ?

Comment: no it is not.  I've been trying to figure out how to run this on a server running exchange 2003 server.  The other question addresses it with exchange 2007

Comment: @Phill: Feel free to remove my edit. You should make the distinction clear in the question. It is in the tags, but honestly, I think many people don't read the tags too thoroughly.

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous..i'll make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function Get-OmaAdminWirelessEnable($obj)
{
    switch($obj)
    {
        $null {"N/A"; break}
        0 {"Enabled"}
        1 {"ActiveSync is Disabled"; break}
        2 {"OMA is Disabled"; break}
        4 {"Disable Always Up-To-Date (AUTD)"; break}
        7 {"All ActiveSync Features disabled"; break}
        default {"Unknown"}
    }
}
$oma = @{name="OMA";expression={ Get-OmaAdminWirelessEnable 
$_.msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable }}
Get-QADUser -sizeLimit 0 -IncludedProperties msExchOmaAdminWirelessEnable | 
select name,$oma
```

Comment: is it possible to query a user by the mailboxguid?